# Xamarin aar binding issue - methods of the class are not visible

Tags: java, xamarin, binding, metadata, aar

I am having a trouble to create dll for Marketingcloud sdk by Salesforce.  Since the last update I am having a trouble to create bindings to access Initialization class. java lib code is as follows:

```
    public final class MarketingCloudSdk extends d.b { ... }

    ...

    static abstract class b
      {
        abstract void a(int paramInt);
      }

    public static @interface a {}
```

What I am doing in Metadata.xml:

```
     <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.salesforce.marketingcloud']/class[@name='a']" name="obfuscated">false</attr>
      <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d']/class[@name='b']" name="obfuscated">false</attr>
     <!--CS0542 'D': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type-->
      <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.salesforce.marketingcloud']/class[@name='d']" name="managedName">dd</attr>
      <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.salesforce.marketingcloud']/class[@name='d']" name="obfuscated">false</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d']/class[@name='b']" name="obfuscated">false</attr>

    <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.salesforce.marketingcloud']">
        <class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="MarketingCloudSdk" static="false" visibility="public" extends="java.lang.Object">
          <constructor deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="MarketingCloudSdk" static="false" type="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk" visibility="public" />
        </class>
      </add-node>
```

Result -> have dll built with Com.Salesforce.Marketingcloud.MarketingCloudSdk available, however the methods of the class are not there apart from  public static abstract interface InitializationListener and public static abstract interface WhenReadyListener.  public static void init(...), public static MarketingCloudSdk getInstance(), etc are not "visible"

I could not find any information on how to describe inherited classes in Metadata.xml any help would be much appreciated

Link to [aar](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/repository/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/marketingcloudsdk/5.4.4/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve this issue - 
the packages are available to download

PM> Install-Package marketingcloudsdkAndroid -Version 1.0.7

PM> Install-Package marketingcloudsdkiOS -Version 1.0.1

For future references - I had to add node to the whole class to make it work.
The project can be looked at my

https://github.com/danilkurkin1/marketingcloudsdk/blob/master/marketingcloudsdk/Transforms/Metadata.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this package

`dotnet add package MarketingCloud.MobilePushSDK.Android`